# Formula for the inverse of Laplacian plus constant in a ball\semiball

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, linear-pde, poissons-equation, elliptic-operators

Let $\lambda_1$ be the first positive eigenvalue of the following problem in the unit semiball $\mathbb{B}_+^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \vert x \vert \leq 1 \text{ and } x_n \geq 0 \}$:

\begin{cases}
\Delta u + \lambda u = 0 \, \quad \text{on } \, \mathbb{B}^n \\
u = 0 \, \quad \text{on } \, \mathbb{S}_+^{n-1} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial N} = 0 \, \quad \text{on } \, \mathbb{B}^n \cap \{x_n = 0\}
\end{cases}

Here, $\mathbb{S}_+^{n-1}$ is the upper hemisphere of the unit sphere and $N = -e_n$ is the outward unit normal to $\mathbb{B}^n \cap \{x_n = 0\}$.

**My question:** is there an explicit formula for the inverse operator $(\Delta + \lambda_1)^{-1}$?

In more concrete terms: let $g \in C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{B}_+^n)$ and suppose that $g$ is orthogonal to the first eigenfunction of the above problem. Is there an explicit formula for the unique $f \in C^{2,\alpha}(\mathbb{B}_+^n)$ such that $(\Delta + \lambda_1)f = g$? In other words, is there an explicit Green function for the problem above?

If not for the semiball, is there such a formula for the whole ball $\mathbb{B}^n$?

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but why is $\Delta + \lambda_1$ invertible in the first place? If $g=0$ and $u$ is a solution to the given equation then $\alpha u $ is a solution for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, so $\Delta + \lambda_1$ is not injective

Comment: Hmm, good point. Maybe we have to exclude the case $g=0$..

Comment: Which operator is $\lambda_1$ an eigenvalue of? Is is $\nabla^2$ or $-\nabla^2$ or something else? From the wording of your question it seems like you want to apply the Fredholm alternative or something similar?